# Maintain constant line width in zooming UIScrollView subView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, drawing, zooming

I have a zooming `UIScrollView` that contains a `UIView` which contains some custom `UIViews`, of the class `MyRectangleView`. Both the `ScrollView` and these `rectangleView`s get a pointer to a common custom `UIViewController`, `MyViewController`.

Is it possible to render these custom views so they appear to *grow* when the scrollView is zoomed, instead of appearing *scaled*?

I do override `drawRect:`, and I have managed to make them change their height, but maintain their width when the scrollView is zoomed, by implementing `scrollViewDidZoom:` in `myViewController` and storing the current `zoomScale` in a property accessible from the `rectangleView`s, then dividing their widths by the `zoomScale`.

I've done the same with the line widths, but as a result of all the scaling, the result looks very fuzzy (although line width stays more or less constant, visually).

Is there a better way to do this?

**How to implement a custom UIView as a subView of a zooming UIScrollView that provides constant line width and doesn't get fuzzy?**

One solution I have thought of would be to make the zoomed views invisible and create other views on top of the scrollView that get their sizes from them, but I'd rather avoid that, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to set these rectangleViews as children of the UIScrollView and NOT have them returned by `viewForZoomingInScrollView:`. This means they will be scrolled, but not zoomed.

In their drawRect:, I transform their frame with the scrollView's zoomScale (provided by the VC). This causes slight artifacts because changing the frame triggers a redraw (without triggering drawRect:), but I'm willing to live with that for the moment.

This means I can set their size as if they were zoomed, but draw them with 1:1 pixels, add text, images, etc., and they remain crisp.

Answer (score 4):

I have successfully used another approach. I wrote a custom method in the subclassed UIView

```
-(void)resize:(CGFloat)scale {    
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1/scale, 1/scale);
```

}

Where scale is the current zoomScale of UIScrollView. This method is called from the following in the parent view

```
-(void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView {

for (PushPin *pushpin in drawingPlaceholder.subviews) {
    if ([pushpin isKindOfClass:[PushPin class]]) {
        [pushpin resize:_scrollView.zoomScale];
    }
}
```

}